# Flask-admin not Enforcing foreign key constraints

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a flask project, using sqlalchemy standalone schema that was not coded for a flask project (hence only uses pure SQLAlchemy)

### Snippet

```
class Drive(Base):
    """
    A drive in an edit station.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'drives'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True,
                           autoincrement=True
                           )
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(64))
    computer_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                    sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(Computer.id)
                                    )
    computer = relationship('Computer', backref='drives')
    # .......... more attr
    current_workgroup_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                             sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(Workgroup.id),
                                             nullable=False
                                             )
    workgroup = relationship('Workgroup', backref='drives')


class Workgroup(Base):
    """
    A workgroup.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'workgroups'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,

                           primary_key=True,
                           autoincrement=True
                           )
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(16))
    shorthand = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(4))
```

The database schema works fine in MySQL. If I have a Drive with a Workgroup, I cannot drop that Workgroup [image]

However, when using `flask-admin` , it does not have such enforcement. I delete the `workgroup` record, and the `drive.workgroup` is updated to a null value. I am not sure how to get the Flask-Admin module to enforce referential integrity,

### AdminViews

```
class DriveAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_auto_select_related = True
    column_display_pk = True
    column_hide_backrefs = False
    column_display_all_relations = True
    column_searchable_list = ('computer.name', 'name', 'workgroup.name')
    #form_columns = ['computer', 'name', 'workgroup', 'is_active']
    column_list = ('computer', 'name', 'workgroup', 'computer.short_description', 'computer.notes',
                   'computer.station_type.description', 'computer.room.name', 'is_active')


class WorkgroupAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_auto_select_related = True
    column_display_pk = True # optional, but I like to see the IDs in the list
    column_hide_backrefs = True
    column_list = ('id', 'name', 'shorthand')
```

### addviews

```
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin Section', template_mode='bootstrap3')
temp_session = EditSession(bind=edit_engine)

admin.add_view(my_admin.ComputerAdmin(Computer, temp_session))
admin.add_view(my_admin.DriveAdmin(Drive, temp_session))
admin.add_view(my_admin.RoomAdmin(Room, temp_session))
admin.add_view(my_admin.WorkgroupAdmin(Workgroup, temp_session))
```

Most of the `column_* = True/False` are me trying to figure this out -_-

edit: I am not looking for the `can_delete` setting. I would like to truly enforce integrity in the sense they should still be able to delete it, as long as nothing is linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if

```
workgroup = relationship('Workgroup', backref='drives')
```

was the issue line. It seems as if `backref` causes this table to be treated as a parent class, causing a many to many relationship, whereinfact I wanted a many to one relationship. updating the line to

`workgroup = relationship('Workgroup')`

Seems to have supported integrity as expected